# Библиотека не зарегистрирована

Tags: access, delphi

Здравствуйте.

Существует следующая проблема. Написана программа на Делфи 2010 (программа для заказа авто-запчастей). В качестве базы данных используется Access-совские mdb файлы (microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0). Проблема в следующем - более чем 100 клиентов пользуются нормально, а у 3-х человек вылетает с ошибкой "Библиотека не зарегистрирована". Может кто-нибудь уже стыкался с такой проблемой? Подскажите, как вылечить....

P.S. Драйвера ODBC на проблемных машинах такие же, как и там, где работает нормально (если это важно).

Comment: наверное используеть какие то внешние длл - ки ?

Comment: нет, никаких внешних dll не используется

Comment: Про jet написал ниже ответа @Чад

Comment: Вы так и не написали, что используете конкретно: Jet напрямую или Jet через ODBC.

Comment: используется ADO

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, проблема в том, что у этих 3х человек 64 битная винда. А аксесс по умолчанию имеет 32битные ODBC драйвера. Появилась на микрософте вроде 64 пак для ODBC, но пару лет назад не было.

Сборка программы под какую архитектуру происходит?

Не знаю как в `Delphi`, в шарпе такая проблема возникает когда компилишь под any cpu - на 32 битных машинах всё ок, на 64 битных - ругается, что не зарегистрирована `dll`.

Comment: Соглашусь, Jet - deprecated. В следующей версии винды вооюще возможно эту технологию будетэневозможно использовать. Совет уходить от mdb и Jet в сторону sql и firebird или любой другой открытой понравившейся реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, я как в прошлом тестировщик, проверил бы процесс монитором (ныне 3.03 версия, качается с сайта микрософта) о какой конкретно длл идет речь.
Пока качается утилитка 2-3-х метровая, стоит проверить политики безопасности? может быть действительно пользователь не имеет админских прав, и ему ограничен доступ к некоторым системным папкам...
После выяснении какой именно модуля не хватает, по мониторингу процессмонитора, можно судить более вещественно.
ЗЫЖ С проблемой конкретной не сталкивался, потому предполагаю, как можно ее локализовать и вычислить.

Comment: Подскажите какой именно монитор Вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx
При помощи него можно отследить обращения к реестру - можно отфильтровать по CLSID если известно. Если класс в реестре нашелся, можно увидеть к какой библиотеки ломимся, как ломимся и что получает в ответ от системы (с точки зрения политики безопасности и файловой системы).
Достаточно гибкая система фильтрации, чтобы не рыться во всем списке логов программы.
PS: А вообще коллеги говорят правильно, проверьте разрядность приложения и подгружаемых библиотек. Недавно это было моей ошибкой - решилось все компиляцией проекта под x86.